# Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar giving black actionbar title text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have been trying to set white text on the actionbar. I went through many questions and I am using theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` and currently using this xml:

```
<style name="TrasnparentActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TransparentActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="TransparentActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_transparent_background</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TransparentTransparentActionBarText</item>
</style>

<style name="TransparentTransparentActionBarText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I have tried different combinations for eg: setting android:titleTextStyle, actionmenutextcolor, or using the actionBar Style Generator. None are working for me.

The above code is from values-v11 but a similar code is in values folder too.

`@drawable/actionbar_transparent_background` is just a shape with `<solid android:color="#00000000"/>`

Comment: Which version of Android are you testing on? You should have 2 separate style files, one for API<14 and the other one for API>=14.
In the one for API<14, remove the "android:" prefix and see if it works. Cheers

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 Hi I am testing with minSDK 10 and as I wrote in the OP that I have a similar code for API<11 and it is with android: prefix removed.
Moreover I have found out that if I use a Light actionbar theme, I get white actionbar text but instead I really need a darkActionBar theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have white text (so dark action bar with light theme) you have to inherit your actionbar style from the correct object: **Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse** and not   Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid

Here is the style.xml file :

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!--  action bar -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

</resources>
```